# Why are PHP string functions not placed in a class.

Tags: php, string, function, methods

I have been trying to wrap my head around this for days now, and yet no answer.
I am currently building a website and I have some set of functions I have built. I later began to refactor them and put related function in a class, but at some point I got confused on whether some related function should also be grouped. From then I began to question myself that although PHP string functions are related why are they not grouped together as a class. 
So what are other good reasons to classify a function?
And when are we not to classify some functions?

Note: I know a php String Class exist.

Comment: For historic reasons. And compatibility.

Comment: `Note: I know a php String Class exist.`.... you mean SplString? Have you actually looked at it, and at the fact that it isn't part of PHP core? And that it is nothing more than a class wrapper for a string var

Comment: But PHP had a string scalar datatype from day #1, and functions to manipulate them; classes of even the most primitive kind weren't introduced until many years later

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour. I feel a valid SO wiki question in the making... and a little gem being posted soon by an expert... End of reviewing. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: @mario ... are you be willing to bring this to wiki level with Jon Skeet precision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`So what are other good reasons to classify a function?`  making a class of methods instead of a group of functions is not as much about grouping them together because they are related, as it is about `scope`, `encapsulation`, and `instantiation`.

when a method is in a class the developer has control over visibility and accessibility. This is also a consideration for the properties of the object.

unlike a group of functions, you can instantiate a class and define values for all of its properties and run its methods as allowed, and then do it again and again while each prior instantiation persists if you like.  An example would be a game with a gun that shoots projectiles, each projectile may be an instantiation of the projectile class with its properties being position, velocity etc...  each bullet has its own set of properties.  There are an unlimited number of examples, many in common use.

I do not group functions into a class because of similarity of the functions, but due to functionality required of the class.

Comment: So you mean php string functions were not made into a method just so they could be available in normal scope.

Comment: No. I'm pretty sure they're just a legacy group of functions because they existed before PHP was object-oriented.

Comment: It is convenient though, I'm a little surprised they did not make a string class later but they can't deprecate the old functions of course, too many applications rely on them.

Comment: I probably should have put that in my answer as well but I thought it was covered comprehensively in the comments to your original question

Comment: I guess they are just legacy code. I also noticed it with mysqli which could be called as functions or through class instantiation.

Comment: The last part though seem to answer my question when you said based on the functionality.